# Global variables in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

The struggle is that I'm trying to add some global variables to my NodeJS app and I take the following error:

```
// I added this line into app.js file
global.atob = require("atob");
```

The error is:

> Property atob is not defined in type NodeJs.Global

Would you have any idea how to fix it, or what exactly to add into NodeJs.Global?

Comment: Why do you want to use `global` instead of something like `const atob = require("atob")` since `require` caches the required packages?

Comment: What, exactly, is reporting the error? Node.js itself? A linter like ESLit? A TypeScript compiler?

Comment: Global variables are generally considered problematic (they make it very easy to write buggy code). Why aren't you just requiring atob into a module scoped variable when you need it? That's how modules are designed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the code should work. There is nothing wrong with the code as such. one thing that you might be missing is to install the `atob` npm package.

Comment: The atob npmpackage is installed :(